# Is this a phishing or hacking attempt using a survey? How do I get rid of this popup?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-5, malware

For the last few days I have been getting a really annoying popup. Every half an hour or so my web browser randomly opens up when I unlock my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5, running Android 6.0.1) and opens up this site:

www.surveygizmo.com/s3/3191047/mul-widget-uninstall-survey

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

The thing is, I don't even know which app or widget they are talking about. I did not recently uninstall anything on my phone, and I don't know what the "mul widget" from the URL is. So I figured it might just be a phishing or hacking attempt by a dubious website or ad, and I just closed the tab. Then, annoyingly, the same site popped up again after a while, so I clicked on "other", added a random reason. Which did not help either. Obviously I did not submit my e-mail, but nothing helped so far and it's starting to piss me off. I couldn't find anyone who had the same issue on the internet, and the only other thing I could think of is adding a random e-mail address but I keep thinking that it looks like there is some software on my phone that has been installed by somebody else, which activates this popup.

I must stress that this popup turns up even if the browser is closed, and it opens the browser by itself.

I also ran Malwarebytes and the AVG AntiVirus multiple times, to no avail.

Does anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 apps associated with this problem, Amber Weather and Histogram. Histogram is a weather widget that has its roots in Amber weather.

I had the same problem. It started after is uninstalled Amber weather but the problem kept occurring. I searched for "Amber" in all of storage and found a folder linked to Histogram called Amber. I uninstalled Histogram and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the list of installed apps and then inspect the list. Uninstall anything that you think you hadn't installed 
especially something like mul widget .

Comment: I tried that, but there was nothing suspicious. Everything that I did not install was a default app by Samsung or Google. And I couldn't find anything related to mul widget...

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help either... It just popped up again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about Samsung's built-in browser?  Try deleting your personal data (menu->settings->privacy).

It could be a piece of code in the cache using it's own delay.  To be sure, delete cookies too, but that might inconvenience your browsing elsewhere.

Have you checked Device Security on Smart Manager?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the built in browser. Thank you for your suggestions, I deleted all cookies and other personal data. And I'm also running a Smart Manager scan right now. I hope that does it! I'll let you know if it does.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers, use comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I seem to have figured out what caused it. I do not use that many widgets so I figured I'd just try to uninstall one after the other and wait for a while to see what happens. This is a rather tedious process but I reckon beggars can't be choosers. After I had uninstalled [AmberWeather](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.ezweather&hl=en) completely I haven't heard anything for two days now.
First I tried uninstalling any widgets I had installed and then uninstalling the app and reinstalling it, or Amber Weather Elite instead of it, but that did not solve the issue. Only after I completely uninstalled it kept it that way did the popups disappear.

I sent an e-mail to the developers asking for information as to why this is happening and how I can get rid of it but I haven't heard anything back from them yet. If I do I will post it here, since some people told me here that they are having the same issue.